# How to use Parsley.js with dynamic content

Tags: forms, validation, dom

I am using parsley.js 2.0.2. for client side form validation.

Now I noticed on the [Parsley Website](http://parsleyjs.org/) that parsley 2.x has dynamic form validation. 
I have a form on my page with parsley. It works correctly and does validate. Now on the same page I have a link that dynamically adds a form from an external file. Issue is now parsley.js won't validate the newly added form.

On the parsley website they have an example where one can use JavaScript to validate but I tried it and it does not work. Here is the snippet code of the example:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="parsley.min.js"></script>

   <form id="form">
   ...
   </form>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#form').parsley();
    </script>
```

I am aware that the content in the DOM changed but is there a way that I can tell parsley to validate this newly added form or something that will trigger the validation process?

I will appreciate the help!
Thanks

**Here is my form on the index.php page (This form does successfully validate):**

```
<form action="server.php" method="post" name="main-form" id="myForm" data-parsley-validate>
<div>
   <label for="njsform-name">Name</label>
   <input name="name" type="text" id="njsform-name" placeholder="Mike" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-minlength="2">
</div>
<div>
   <label for="njsform-email">Surname</label>
   <input name="email" type="text" id="njsform-email" placeholder="Gates" data-parsley-required="true" parsley-minlength="2">
</div>
<div class="submitWrap">
   <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Apply Now" />
</div>
```

**Here is the link that gets the external content**

```
<ul class="services-list">
     <li><a class="s-option" href="views/form-short_term_loans.php">My Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Here is the code I am using to dynamically change the content (does successfully retrieve external form and populates):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('.services-list li a').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
            var toLoad = hash+'.html #form-section';
            $('#form-section').load(toLoad)
        }                                           
    });

    $('.services-list li a').click(function(){                                
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #form-section';
        $('#form-section').hide('fast',loadContent);
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#intro-section').append('<span id="load">Getting required form...</span>');
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#form-section').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#form-section').show('normal',hideLoader());
        }
        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
        return false;

    });

});
```

The second form is just a duplicate but the form id is **myForm2** and the name **second-form**

Comment: How did your link add your form? can you put your code there plz?

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to

```
 $('#xxxxxx').parsley();
```

After the load of the new form. With **xxxxx** the id of the new form inserted in the DOM

Comment: I have tried a call like the one you gave as well as `new Parsley('#xxxxx');` but it still does not work

Comment: `new Parsley('#xxxxx');` what? Use it like `$('#xxxxxx').parsley();`

Comment: When you do new ... you create a new object of Parsley whith an argument which is a string '#xxxx'.



When you do $('#xxx').parsley(). You call a method on a jquery object

Comment: Ok I added `<script type="text/javascript"> $('#myForm2').parsley(); </script>` after the new form but it still doesn't want to work. It just runs the forms action and skips the validation.

Comment: I have tested the above and it works but it does not work when content is dynamically added. Might be something wrong with the way I request external pages I think. Thanks a million for the help though